# Uploading a file to Google Bucket from local system using Airflow - Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, airflow

So I am running this operator on airflow

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs import FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

gcp_operator = \
    FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id='gcp_task',
        src='/Users/john/Documents/tmp',
        dst='gs://constantine-bucket',
        bucket='constantine-bucket',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='DataScience',
        mime_type='Folder',
        dag=dag
    )
```

When I run this I get an error

```
"error": "invalid_scope",
"error_description": "\u0026quot;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write\u0026quot; is not a valid audience string
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to run this operator on airflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a missing dependency. You should be able to install the GCP hooks and operators using:

```
pip install apache-airflow[gcp_api]
```

For more info, refer to this page: https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: I can install this on my PC. But how to make these installations on Airflow?

Comment: @JohnConstantine I guess that depends a lot on how you are running Airflow everywhere else than your PC. Maybe you could elaborate on that? Quite possibly that is a question on it's own.

Comment: @rob So I did install the library and get another error. I have updated the question with it

Comment: @JohnConstantine Might be a typo somewhere, read the FileToGCP doc here (https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html), and double check all of your config variables and args match up with your GCP