# Airflow LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator marks the task with success but the file is not uploaded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm trying to upload a file from my local machine to GCS and I'm using the `LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator`. I'm following this howto https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/google/transfer/local_to_gcs.html#prerequisite-tasks. I've set up a connection to GCP with a path to a json file. This is the DAG code:

```
import os

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.local_to_gcs import LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator
from airflow.utils import dates

BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket-name'
PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE = '...path-to/airflow/dags/example-text.txt'
DESTINATION_FILE_LOCATION = '/test-dir-input/example-text.txt'

with models.DAG(
    'example_local_to_gcs',
    default_args=dict(start_date=dates.days_ago(1)),
    schedule_interval=None,
) as dag:
    upload_file = LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator(
        gcp_conn_id='custom_gcp_connection',
        task_id="upload_file",
        src=PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE,
        dst=DESTINATION_FILE_LOCATION,
        bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        mime_type='text/plain'
    )
```

When I trigger the DAG it is marked as a success but the file is not in the bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem with your `path_to_upload` and `destination_file_location`.

To give you an idea, here's a [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225407/uploading-a-file-to-google-bucket-from-local-system-using-airflow-python) that could also help you. The relevant parameters similar to yours were declared like this for example:

```
src='/Users/john/Documents/tmp',
dst='gs://constantine-bucket',
bucket='constantine-bucket',
```

You should remove the `...` and make sure that the `destination_file_location` refers to your bucket name or the folder inside it like this:

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket-name'
PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE = '/path-to/airflow/dags/example-text.txt'
DESTINATION_FILE_LOCATION = 'gs://bucket-name/example-text.txt'

# Or in a folder on your bucket
# DESTINATION_FILE_LOCATION = 'gs://bucket-name/folder/example-text.txt'
```

Comment: As per [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_local/index.html#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_local) documentation, a **similar** operator (GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator) bucket arg "Must not contain 'gs://' prefix"

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the trick for me.

Please note that the service account used must have `storage.objects` permissions in the destination-bucket to write the file.

[image]

```py
import os
import datetime
from pathlib import Path

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.local_to_gcs import LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator

comp_home_path = Path(conf.get("core", "dags_folder")).parent.absolute()
comp_bucket_path = "data/uploaded" # <- if your file is within a folder
comp_local_path = os.path.join(comp_home_path, comp_bucket_path)

default_args = {
   'owner': 'airflow',
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'start_date': datetime.datetime.today(),
   'end_date': None,
   'email': ['somename@somecompany.com'],
   'email_on_failure': True,
   'email_on_retry': True,
   'retries': 1,
   'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
   }

sch_interval = None

dag = DAG(
   'mv_local_to_GCS',
   default_args=default_args,
   tags=["example"],
   catchup=False,
   schedule_interval=sch_interval
   )

mv_local_gcs = LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator(
       task_id="local_to_gcs",
       src=comp_local_path+"/yourfilename.csv",# PATH_TO_UPLOAD_FILE
       dst="somefolder/yournewfilename.csv",# BUCKET_FILE_LOCATION
       bucket="yourproject",#using NO 'gs://' nor '/' at the end, only the project, folders, if any, in dst
       dag=dag
   )

start = DummyOperator(task_id='Starting', dag=dag)

start >> mv_local_gcs
```